# JPA saves entity to database with correct timezone but returns wrong timezone

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Hi I have problem with JPA timezone. My model has two field

```
@Data
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "cases")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_cases", sequenceName = "seq_cases", allocationSize = 1)
public class Cases implements Serializable {

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Instant lastModifiedDate;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Instant createdDate;
}
```

I am using JPA repository as following.

```
@Repository
public interface CaseRepository extends JpaRepository<Cases, UUID> {
}
```

In Service,

```
var savedCase = caseRepository.save(caseDTO)
```

I am saving Case entity with `caseRepository.save()` method without `lastModifiedDate` and `createdDate` in `caseDTO`. I am not sure when they are generated but those two fields are saved to database with timezone GMT+3. The response of `caseRepository.save()` which is `savedCase` has those two fields with timezone GMT+0.

So as summary response of caseRepository.save() method and record in database has different time zones.

Also this is my application.yml file and I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`

```
spring:
  jackson:
    time-zone: Asia/Istanbul

  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          time_zone: Asia/Istanbul
```

Edit:

When I add this method to repository

```
@Repository
public interface CaseRepository extends JpaRepository<Cases, UUID> {
    Optional<Cases> findById(UUID id);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var foundCase =  caseRepository.findById(UUID.fromString(id)).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("Case not found."));
```

foundCase returned with GMT+3 again. So problem only occurs in save method.

Edit 2:

This is the database when I use save() method.
[image: Database]

This is the debug mode. You are seeing response of save() method. As you can see there is difference.  :

[image: Debug]

And this is response of findById method
[image: findById]

Comment: Your Java fields are of type `Instant`. And instant doesn't *have* a time zone (or even a UTC offset, which isn't the same thing) - it's just an instant in time. (It doesn't help that we don't know what kind of database you're using, or what the field types in the database are...)

Comment: I am using Postgres and types of fields are timestamp in database.

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you have a look at edit I have made?

Comment: "foundCase returned with GMT+3 again." seems pretty unclear to me, and you haven't addressed anything in my comment within the question. (All relevant information should be in the question.) As far as I'm aware, the timestamp field in Postgres doesn't store UTC offset information either - again, it's just an instant in time. It might be *displayed* with respect to some time zone, but that's not the same as the value itself having a UTC offset.

Comment: findByID() method returns those two fields with GMT+3 as they are appear in database on the contrary save() method saves entity to database with those fields are in GMT+3 but returns GMT+0

Comment: "findByID() method returns those two fields with GMT+3" - in what way? What's the return type in Java? How *exactly* are you observing "with GMT+3"? Again, you should *edit your question* to make all of this much, much clearer.

Comment: "This is the database when I use save() method." You're showing a UI representation of the values. (We can't tell which UI.) If it's deciding to display the values in UTC+3, then so be it. That doesn't mean the value inherently "knows" that it's UTC+3. It looks like the same instant in time is being represented - in other words, there's no actual bug.

Answer (score -1):

It looks more likely a database timezone issue than a jpa issue.

Please first try executing `now()` in Postgresql and check the timezone of the database.

My guess is:

As both `lastModifiedDate` and `createdDate` are set `nullable = false`, when **saving** null values, timestamps of the db timezone were generated to the fields.

When **finding** the entities, the timestamps are being treated as UTC, and since your application is in +3 timezone, it adds 3 hours to both fields.

Personally I would suggest using `j.u.Date` instead of `Instant` when saving entities to db.